# Creating a table with max number of rows (ORACLE)

Tags: database, oracle, rows

Is there any way to limit the maximum number of rows when I create a table in Oracle?

Comment: if you just want to ensure to keep the overall size down, maybe ask your DBA to setup a small tablespace (autoextend off or set maxsize to low value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the table has a numeric key, you could add a check constraint that states that the key does not exceed a specific value:

```
ALTER TABLE turnip
ADD CONSTRAINT check_turnip_id
CHECK (turnip_id <= 50)
/
```

Comment: +1 for Better idea on using check constraint. Shouldn't it be unique key??

Comment: if you wanted to go down this route you would need the key to be unique, yes - but that would be a separate constraint, probably a primary key

Comment: Exactly this is what I had in mind :) A PK (or a sequence based column) with Check constraint on number of rows

Comment: You could easily bypass this by using negative or non-integer numbers - unless you define additional constraints. Creating a sequence has a problem when you delete anthing from that table, since the sequence continues to increase their value.

Comment: I didn't say it was foolproof, just that it was a possibility. You could easily change the check to be `BETWEEN 1 AND 50` to avoid negative numbers, it just depends on the specific requirements, which we don't have

Comment: You have to develop additional logic. E.g. insert 50 rows -> delete randomly 5 rows -> what are the "free" ID's which can be used again? You have to provide a trigger (or PL/SQL procedure) providing free ID's if they are sparse, which may happen.

Comment: A simple method to automatically fill in gaps from deleted rows is to create the sequence with a MINVALUE and MAXVALUE and CYCLE; then add some code to the application to automatically try another sequence value whenever it gets DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX; of course, in the event that the table is "full", it will need some exit strategy (e.g. only try 50 times to find a free gap). Performance may suffer with this strategy, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a statement trigger "BEFORE INSERT" and check there the nubmer of rows.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BI_MY_TABLE
    BEFORE INSERT ON MY_TABLE
DECLARE
    CountRows NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO CountRows
    FROM MY_TABLE;

    IF CountRows > 100 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Only 100 records are allowed');    
    END IF;
END;
/
```

However, this trigger does not work properly in a multi-user environment.

Comment: Trigger? That too checking rowcount on each insert? AFAIK avoid trigger

Comment: I've create a trigger since the max number of rows is 100 and that shouldn't be a problem with execution time, but will be great to know how to limit the table size when I create it.

Comment: You cannot perform Select on the table, inside a trigger, on which it is fired. It will through Mutating trigger error.

Comment: This is **not** a Row level trigger, there is no `FOR EACH ROW` clause in it. It works!

Comment: Without some form of locking, a trigger might still allow more than 100 rows because it will not "see" rows inserted by a concurrent, yet-to-be committed transaction.  For example: i) start with an empty table, ii) in transaction A, insert 99 rows, iii) in transaction B, insert 99 rows, iv) commit transaction A, v) commit transaction B.  An integer column with a unique constraint and check constraints on the upper and lower bounds is a more robust solution.  You might also consider a refresh-on-commit materialized view with a check constraint.

Comment: @Art: did you read the answer properly and also the other comments. The trigger works!

Comment: @Brian Camire: This you can prevent easily by defining a simple Primary Key on the table - which you should have anyway. Then session B is locked until session A makes a COMMIT/ROLLBACK.

Comment: @Wernfried, a primary key constraint will block transaction B only if transaction B tries to insert (or update) a value in the primary key column(s) that transaction A has already inserted (or updated).  In other words, the trigger plus primary key constraint will not prevent more than 100 rows from being inserted if the rows all have distinct values in the primary key column(s).

Comment: @Brian Camire: You are right, so finally using only the trigger is not sufficient. However, using a Primary key plus a constraint which checks the range is not sufficient either. You must write a trigger which sets the value of primary key, because when you delete something then the primary key values become sparse.