# Insert in Oracle table if rows size is under 300

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this table in which I want to have maximum 300 rows of data:

```
CREATE TABLE "ADMIN"."SESSIONS" 
   (    "SESSIONID" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "SESSIONTYPE" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "USERID" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "ACTIVITYSTART" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "ACTIVITYEND" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "ACTIVITY" CLOB, 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "IPADDRESS" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "LOGINTIME" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "LOGOUTTIME" TIMESTAMP (6)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
```

Can you tell me how I can insert into the table only if the maximum number is not reached? I want to do this using prepared statement.

Comment: It's not difficult if there will be only one thread which performs the insert and more difficult if there will be several threads. What's your case?

Comment: How important is this restriction? You can allow to insert more than 300 rows and then use job to delete unnecessary rows, you can use view with condition `rownum <=300` to hide them...

Comment: how about this: INSERT INTO SESSIONS (SESSIONID, SESSIONTYPE, USERID, ACTIVITYSTART, ACTIVITYEND, ACTIVITY, USERNAME, IPADDRESS, LOGINTIME, LOGOUTTIME) select ?, null, ?, sysdate, sysdate, ?, 'admina', ?, sysdate, sysdate FROM SESSIONS  having COUNT(*) < ?;

Comment: Please explain why you wan to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally close this question as a duplicate of [Creating a table with max number of rows (ORACLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047903/creating-a-table-with-max-number-of-rows-oracle). Basically, it's nearly impossible and if you need to do this you're probably doing something wrong. You don't want to be calculating the number of records in a table prior to inserting into it - this is a lot of excess work.

However, given the names of the column names in your table there's probably an easier way of doing this. Alter the [`SESSIONS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams220.htm#REFRN10197) parameter to be 300. This will restrict your database to 300 concurrent sessions. If an attempt is made to create a 301<sup>st</sup> session the error *ORA-00018 maximum number of sessions exceeded* will be raised. If you are restricting the number of concurrent users you may have to be relatively aggressive about dropping unused connections - it depends on the number of users you're expecting.

If you *still* need to maintain the table after this then you can use BEFORE LOGON and BEFORE LOGOFF triggers to maintain it (though I'm not sure what `ACTIVITYEND` and `LOGOUTTIME` could be used for), the BEFORE LOGIN trigger would insert into the table and the BEFORE LOGOFF would delete from it.

Comment: is there any other solution?

Comment: If I knew of one I'd have posted it @Peter; that doesn't mean one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID column to your table, control its values using a sequence as suggested by Jeffrey Kemp in [Creating a table with max number of rows (ORACLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047903/creating-a-table-with-max-number-of-rows-oracle) to which @Ben has been pointing.

(Sorry - not allowed to comment, yet. So if this helps, credit Ben, please. Otherwise: What else is needed?)